# comming up from background state the app is stuck in ios objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, background-process

i run my app properly in current state of Application,But when i go outside the app from current state to background state  and again come back to current state the application is stuck every time same process is followed but ,i can't understand what happen in this case.?

1) Application Running then when API is called (Loading Animation)

2) I go to background mode (by home button or lock screen)

3) When i came back to application stuck(frozen) and memory is being increase continuously.

Please ,Help me gyus.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please specify your error more accurately. What do you mean by "the same process is followed"? Do you mean the process is working but stuck?

Comment: have you write any code in didbcomeactive method in appdelegate class?

Comment: Have you used custom url scheme in your app? please write down the step and conditions.

Comment: @TMob hello, app is currently running fine ,but when i click on Home Button in device and app goes to background state and after that 5 to 10 sec  again i open the app ,then app is open but it's stuck(frozen) the apps. Also i notice application memory being increase continuously.

Comment: @kb920 No , in didbecomeActive method noithing to write any code

Comment: I think it's because of loader. UI can't update in background. Just for check stop Animation and check the result.

Comment: @kb920 yes i tried that, but UI also going to stuck (Frozen).

Comment: I hope you have remove loading animation and tried!

Comment: I think you are synchronously calling the API when the app became active so it stuck until u get the response from the API url , use asynchronous method to call the API

Comment: @Vignesh ,yes bro i already call API aysnc by dataTaskWithRequest of NSURLSession

Comment: @Hirenkanetiya you just comment API call and check is it works or not?

Comment: did you use handler under the dataTaskWithRequest

Comment: @Vignesh yes i use error handler like  this block :completionHandler:^(NSData *data,
                                    NSURLResponse *response,
                                    NSError *error)